# Magento2 Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Gogoesho

Tags: magento2

[image]

My code display this error , anyone can help me , many thanks

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   Gogoeshop\ProductWarranty\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must
>   be an instance of Magento\Customer\Model\Session, instance of
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory given, called in
>   C:\Apache-2.4.7-win64-VC11\htdocs\magentopos2\generated\code\Gogoeshop\ProductWarranty\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor.php
>   on line 14 and defined in
>   C:\Apache-2.4.7-win64-VC11\htdocs\magentopos2\app\code\Gogoeshop\ProductWarranty\Controller\Index\Index.php:9
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\Apache-2.4.7-win64-VC11\htdocs\magentopos2\generated\code\Gogoeshop\ProductWarranty\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor.php(14):
>   Gogoeshop\ProductWarranty\Controller\Index\Index->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory)) #1
>   C:\Apache-2.4.7-win64-VC11\htdocs\magentopos2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(111):
>   Gogoeshop\ProductWarranty\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\
>   in
>   C:\Apache-2.4.7-win64-VC11\htdocs\magentopos2\app\code\Gogoeshop\ProductWarranty\Controller\Index\Index.php
>   on line 9

Answer (score 1):

Try Compiling the code with this command: `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just run following command using Command Line Mode

```
rm -rf var/generation/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Magento caches the constructors in `var/generation` folder, so if you clear the `var/generation` content then Magento will regenerate the interceptor.

```
rm -rf var/generation
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolving it by following steps

First, you need to remove generated/code/* and var/cache/*

```
rm -rf generated/code/* var/cache/*
```

Second, Clean the cache

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Third, Change the file permission

```
sudo chmod 777 -R generated/ var/ pub/
```

Fourth, run Generated Compile the code

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands one by one:-

```
rm -rf var/*

rm -rf generated

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: Getting the same error, https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/318269/57334 how to solve the issue? @Girase Priyanka